# Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class TextView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

So my application works perfectly while running it on the virtual device. When I tried to build a signed apk I got these errors like these:

```
Warning: androidx.media.AudioAttributesCompatParcelizer: can't find referenced field 'android.support.v4.media.AudioAttributesImpl mImpl' in program class android.support.v4.media.AudioAttributesCompat
Warning: androidx.media.AudioAttributesImplApi21Parcelizer: can't find referenced field 'android.media.AudioAttributes mAudioAttributes' in program class android.support.v4.media.AudioAttributesImplApi21
Warning: androidx.media.AudioAttributesImplApi21Parcelizer: can't find referenced field 'int mLegacyStreamType' in program class android.support.v4.media.AudioAttributesImplApi21
Warning: androidx.media.AudioAttributesImplBaseParcelizer: can't find referenced field 'int mUsage' in program class android.support.v4.media.AudioAttributesImplBase
Warning: androidx.media.AudioAttributesImplBaseParcelizer: can't find referenced field 'int mFlags' in program class android.support.v4.media.AudioAttributesImplBase
Warning: androidx.media.AudioAttributesImplBaseParcelizer: can't find referenced field 'int mLegacyStream' in program class android.support.v4.media.AudioAttributesImplBase
```

So I added this to my proguard file:

```
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
```

And now the apk is building successfully but after I start my application it crashes with this error. Why does this happen when my app works fine on running on virtual device?

I can't seem to find the problem even after reading other answers. Here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/azureColorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@color/azureColorPrimary">


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_1"
    android:layout_width="277dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="5sp"
    android:paddingStart="10sp"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"

    android:textSize="25sp"
    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/record_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="567dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
        android:paddingTop="10sp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/azureColorPrimary"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="310dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="494dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/guide"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/show_tutorial"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/guide"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="73dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_tut" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.arahasya.sap.forwardkey/com.arahasya.sap.forwardkey.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class TextView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class TextView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class TextView
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.bk.d()' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v7.widget.bm.onTextChanged(Unknown Source)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5133)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4954)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1825)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1035)
    at android.support.v7.widget.bm.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.widget.bm.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.app.r.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.app.r.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
    at android.support.v7.app.r.b(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.app.o.setContentView(Unknown Source)
    at com.arahasya.sap.forwardkey.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6955)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
2018-10-24 01:25:52.356 4679-24128/? E/NetworkScheduler: Invalid component specified.
```

Comment: Open your gradle.properties and add android.enableAapt2=false

Comment: Still app crashing with same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that when you set minifyEnabled to false it will work. If it's the case, It seems that you have an issue with proguard.
Try to add this line :

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
```

Comment: yes minifyEnabled to false did the work. I did this before your comment but as you are right I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Still have the warnings with -keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }

Answer (score 0):

All things working fine :

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/title_1"
  android:layout_width="277dp"
  android:layout_height="50dp"
  android:padding="5sp"
  android:paddingStart="10sp"
  android:text="@string/title"
  android:textColor="#ffffff"
  android:textSize="25sp"
  tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"
 />
```

**Problem is here :**

```
  android:padding="5sp"
  Only you just need to change this thing android:padding="5dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had these warnings and I added these lines to my proguard-rules.pro file :

```
-dontwarn androidx.**
-keep class androidx.** { *; }
-keep interface androidx.** { *; }
```